# Visual Studio 19 Crashes when it runs on AWS instance

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Currently I’m working on a customized visual studio extension and when I working with the extension on AWS instance, suddenly visual studio crashes giving “Microsoft Visual studio 19 has stopped working” error.But this issue cannot be seen in the local machine environment. It can be seen only in the AWS environment.

So when I analyzed the issue it seems that,exception throws when it hits below lines of code.

```
var temp = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
{
//Some code here
});
```

Further I tried using a try -catch around the code segment, but still this issue comes.
Appreciate any advice or opinions on this !

Comment: It wouldn't say "Visual Studio 19 has stopped working" because the latest version of visual studio is 16. Which is branded as Visual Studio **20**19. There has only been one version of visual studio in recent memory where the internal version number and the year branding coincided (10/2010)

Comment: Sorry It's a mistake @Damien_The_Unbeliever It prompts as  "Visual Studio 2019 has stopped working"